# Regular expression for currency matching "23a" where unexpected

Tags: swift, nsregularexpression

Using the following code in a playground, my test string "23a" matches my test and I'm not sure why.

```swift
     extension String {
         var isCurrencyString: Bool {
             return currencyString == self
         }

         var currencyString: String {
             let input = self as NSString

             guard let decimalSeparator = NSLocale.current.decimalSeparator
                 , let groupingSeparator = NSLocale.current.groupingSeparator
                 else { return "" }

             let testPattern = "^-?([0-9]{1,3}(\(groupingSeparator)?[0-9])*)(\(decimalSeparator)?[0-9]{0,2})$"

             guard let expression = try? NSRegularExpression(pattern: testPattern) else { return "" }

             let matches = expression.matches(in: self, options: [], range: NSMakeRange(0, input.length)).map {
                 input.substring(with: $0.range)
             }

             return matches.first ?? ""
         }
     }

     let tester = "23a"

     print(tester.currencyString)    //23a
     print(tester.isCurrencyString)  //true
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is at your 3rd capturing group .? You need to escape the period otherwise it will be interpreted as any character:

```
guard 
    var decimalSeparator = NSLocale.current.decimalSeparator, 
    var groupingSeparator = NSLocale.current.groupingSeparator
else { return "" }
if groupingSeparator ==  "." { groupingSeparator = #"\."# }
if decimalSeparator ==  "." { decimalSeparator = #"\."# }
```

You should also set the number of digits in your 2nd capturing group to 3

try

```
let testPattern = "^-?([0-9]{1,3}(\(groupingSeparator)?[0-9]{3})*)(\(decimalSeparator)?[0-9]{0,2})$"
```